# Validar email en jTextField Java

Tags: java, regex, jtextfield

Tengo el campo `jTextField_email` y quisiera validar el `email` cuando pierda el foco el `jTextField`.

**Código:**

```
public boolean isEmail (String correo){
        Pattern pat = null;
        Matcher mat = null;
        pat = Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\-\\_\\+]+(\\.[\\w\\-\\_]+)*@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$");
        mat = pat.matcher(correo);
        if(mat.find()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

private void textfield_emailFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                          
        if(!isEmail(textfield_email.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Debes validar el email!", "ATENCIÓN ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_email.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

El código anterior funciona correctamente pero...

**¿Cómo invalido caracteres como !/&%$=)( para el email?** Mi idea es invalidar directamente la tecla incorrecta al teclearla con el evento `KeyTyped` (no en el patrón, el patrón del `email` solo para el formato).

**Código:**

```
private void textfield_direccionKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             

if(textfield_direccion.getText().length()>49){
                evt.consume(); //hace que esa pulsación de tecla se rechace.
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); //sonido de no aceptar más caracteres.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes cachar los eventos del teclado con un `KeyListener` y descartarlos cuando se teclee un caracter no deseado:

```
final List<Character> invalidos = new ArrayList<Character>(); // Lista de caracteres vacía 
for( char c : "!/&%$=)(".toCharArray() ) // Una cadena con caracteres inválidos
    invalidos.add(c); // Para convertir arreglo char en lista de Character

textfield_direccion.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke){
        if( invalidos.contains(ke.getKeyChar()) ) // ¿Es caracter inválido?
            ke.consume(); // Descarta el evento
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función `replaceAll()` y pasarle una expresión regular con los caracteres que quieras evitar, luego asignas la nueva cadena a `textfield_direccion`:

```
private void textfield_direccionKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {  

       String texto = textfield_direccion.getText();

              texto = texto.replaceAll("[!/&%$=)]", "");   

              textfield_direccion.setText(texto);



if(textfield_direccion.getText().length()>49){
                evt.consume(); //hace que esa pulsación de tecla se rechace.
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); //sonido de no aceptar más caracteres.
            }
        }
```